# Get second last row for every record in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I had table lets say table_inventory. On the table_inventory i put a trigger for every update of stock insert new row in audit_inventory table:

table column are look like:

**table_inventory**

|sr_id|inventory_id|p_name|stock|

**audit_inventory**

|insert_time||sr_id|inventory_id|p_name|stock|

Now my problem is for every inventory_id of **table_inventory** there are multiple entry in **audit_inventory** as i put trigger for every update of stock insert a row with time in **audit_inventory**, so i want to select second last stock value for every inventory_id  of **table_inventory**. I write some cte to do that but unable to get for every inventory_id.

```
 WITH CTE as
    (select inventory_id,stock from table_inventory),
cte_1 as(
      SELECT
        stock,
        row_number() over (order by insert_time desc) rn
      FROM audit_inventory where inventoryid in (select inventory_id from cte)
    ),cte_2 as(
    SELECT stock
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rn = 2)
select * from cte,cte_1;
```

The above query retrns the second last value for single inventory_id but did not understand how to write query for getting second last row value for every inventory_id of **table_inventory**.

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: ok Thanks for the response @VaoTsun

Comment: please provide some DATA SAMPLE and problem you meet

Comment: I update the question please check.

Comment: How exactly are you selecting `good_stock` from `CTE` when `CTE` doesn't have a column of that name?

Comment: I am sorry my bad i update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this. I guess this is what you want:

```
WITH CTE as
( SELECT
        stock,
        inventory_id,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY inventoryid order by insert_time desc) rn
  FROM audit.inventory 
)

SELECT
    CTE.stock,
    ti.inventory_id,
    ti.stock
FROM
    table_inventory ti
    inner join CTE on CTE.inventory_id=ti.inventory_id
WHERE
     CTE.rn=2
```